# Cloning entities and resetting Id's and foreign keys in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a number of tables in my SQL database that link to each other via foreign keys.

[image]

The Id's are auto-increment identities.

My application allows the user to construct certain templates, and add them to the database.

To retrieve a full template I use this syntax (which I am not sure is entirely correct)

```
private Template GetFullTemplate(int Id)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            return context.Templates
                .Where(template => template.Id == Id)
                .Include(lines => lines.TemplateLines)
                .ThenInclude(moi => moi.MethodOfInput)

                .Include(lines => lines.TemplateLines)
                .ThenInclude(unit => unit.UnitOfMeasure)

                .Include(lines => lines.TemplateLines)
                .ThenInclude(reading => reading.TemplateReadings)
                .ThenInclude(type => type.ReadingType)

                .Include(columns => columns.TemplateColumns)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The users would like to clone a full template, then change a few details and save it to the database as a new template. Therein lies my problem.

**The Problem:**
The issue I have is that all of the related entities need their own Id's set to zero AND the foreign key Id's setting to zero before I can insert the new template.

The only way I can think of doing this is to manually go through each field, setting everything to zero like so...

```
    Template.Id = 0
    TemplateLine.Id = 0
    Templateline.TemplateId = 0

etc....
```

As my database gets more tables I will need to keep adding more lines of this zeroing code.

I have scoured the internet to try to find anyone that may have handled this issue, but to no avail.

I was hoping there may be some elegant way of doing this rather than have to write lines and lines of code that sets all of these to zero. I don't think my situation is particularly unique, so I had hoped there would be a better way of achieving this.

Or maybe my approach is completely wrong? And advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the user works on a UI, right? I'd suggest not to use directly the DB entities on your UI, but map them on view-model classes when retrieving them and map them back to the DB entities when saving the new tamplate.
In this way, you encapsulate the transformations between different models inside functions; when you create the entities for the new template, you can leave the foreign keys with the default values (0).

Comment: Yes, the user uses a UI to accomplish this. Thanks for the suggestion, I could probably use something like 'automapper' to achieve this approach.

Comment: If you `Add` the template to a new context all object should get the `Added` state, irrespective of their key values, and EF should insert them all as a cloud of new objects.

Comment: @GertArnold Unfortunately that is the issue I have here. As all of the templates id's are populated from the original query. When I try to add them, EF is trying to insert those identity columns and throws an error. So I think my only was around it is to use Manuel's suggestion.

Comment: But EF should ignore the Id values in INSERT statements if the columns are configured as identity columns.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case. Unless I explicitly set the identity columns to zero, it throws an error "SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Template' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."